# How use nested for loop with char and integer?

Tags: java

I'm creating a form to add a new book to the library system, in which the user gives some details about the book, like "title" or "category".

- In the "Author" field, considering that the book can be written by more than one author, the system asks the user for the number of authors.
- If the user inputs the number "n", then the system iterates "n" times through the "Author" field and collects the inputs into a String ArrayList.
- My goal is to add a letter after the field description to differentiate one input from the other, so if there are "n" authors, then the system will ask for "Author A" and then "Author B", and so on.

Here's my code snippet:

```
//The system asks for the String "numberOfAuthors".
for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numberOfAuthors); i++) {
    //I limited the number of authors to maximum 3, that's why it iterates until "C".
    for (char abc = 'A'; abc < 'D'; abc++) {

        System.out.print("\nAuthor " + abc + " :" + "\n> ");
        String author = userInput.getString();

        while (!authorPattern.matcher(author).matches()) {
            System.out.print("\n\"" + author + "\"" + authorWarning);
            System.out.print("\nAuthor " + abc + " :" + "\n> ");
            author = userInput.getString();
        }

        authors.add(author.toLowerCase());
        setAuthor(String.valueOf(authors));
    }
}
```

- The problem is that the system iterates "i" number times through char "abc", so in the following output where `numberOfAuthors = 3`, it iterates through "Author A" to "Author C", 3 times.

  ```
  Number of Authors:
  > 3

  Author A :
  > john doe

  Author B :
  > maria young

  Author C :
  > sinead parks

  Author A :
  >
  ```
- I did try breaking the nested loop as I know it is (not always)
  considered bad practice, but it didn't work.
- I also tried changing char to String so I could compare "abc" to "i", but it also didn't work.
- If there is another way of achieving it I'm all ears.
- Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't nest loops! Use a single for loop

Comment: Why do you think you need the inner loop? What is that supposed to achieve? Why not just print `"Author " + i`.

Comment: @Polygnome I did it, it works just fine. I just wanted to get "Author A" instead of  "Author 0".

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am aware that it's bad practice, but if there's another way to achieving it I would like to learn.

Comment: `char[] letters = {'A', 'B', 'C'};` and then in your print: `"Author " + chars[i]`.

Comment: @Polygnome I just did. Got rid of the second loop and applied what you said, it works just fine. thanks!

Comment: ``"Author " + (char)(i + 'A')``

Comment: @NomadMaker `(char)(i + 'A')` That is heavily discouraged as it relies on ASCII staying the encoding forever. Its bad practice, don't do that. It also introduces subtle bugs when `i` becomes larger. It doesn't fail, but chugs along while potentially messing up the stdout.. At least wrap it in an `i % 26`.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Polygnome advice I got this:

```
         //I got rid of the second loop, now it works just fine.
          char[] letters = {'A', 'B', 'C'};

            for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(numberOfAuthors); i++) {
                System.out.print("\nAuthor " + letters[i] + " :" + "\n> ");
                String author = userInput.getString();

                while (!authorPattern.matcher(author).matches()) {
                    System.out.print("\n\"" + author + "\"" + authorWarning);
                    System.out.print("\nAuthor " + letters[i] + " :" + "\n> ");
                    author = userInput.getString();
                }

                authors.add(author.toLowerCase());
                setAuthor(String.valueOf(authors));
            }
        }
```

And the output:

```
Number of Authors:
> 3

Author A :
> john doe

Author B :
> maria young

Author C :
> sinead parks

Number of Categories:
>
```

Thanks!